# How can send a url to telegram bot?

Tags: bash, curl, bots, telegram

I write a code to send a proxy link to my telegram bot but when i send the request
my proxy link don't send complete

this is my code

```
#/bin/bash

TOKEN="***********************"
ID="************"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"
PRLINK="tg://proxy?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&port=443&secret=eeb000000000000000000000000000"

curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$ID -d text=${PRLINK} > /root/sendResult
```

and this response

```
{ [..] ,"text":"tg://proxy?server=18.202.178.109", [..]}
```

in response

"text":"tg://proxy?server=18.202.178.109" no equal to PRLINK that me send with curl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to URL encoding: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

In a nutshell, you should **encode** the ampersand character in order to let the entire URL be considered properly.

So that, the ampersand character is encoded as `%26`, therefore:

Your code should be:

```
#/bin/bash

TOKEN="***********************"
ID="************"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$TOKEN/sendMessage"
PRLINK="tg://proxy?server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx%26port=443%26secret=eeb000000000000000000000000000"

curl -s -X POST $URL -d chat_id=$ID -d text=${PRLINK} > /root/sendResult
```